# Democratic photography social network(or app)

Tags: sharing

I will explain the title: I saw recently an article online talking about a photography sharing site (or app,  can't remember) which didn't favour the visibility of photos coming from  users with large bases of followers, instead each photo submitted is proposed (shows in the feed) to a fixed number of other users of the site. Those users can choose to "keep or pass" over the photo, if they keep the photo will be shown to other users, gaining momentum, otherwise it will stop being shown.
Can't really remember the name of the site, can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a photography question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the iPhone app [ROL](http://rolapp.co/). [Petapixel](http://petapixel.com/2015/06/07/rol-is-like-the-tinder-of-competitive-photo-sharing/) did a short article on it a while ago.

Comment: Yes, it was the article I was searching for. Thanks.
Sadly it's for Apple only, I think it's a cool experiment.